# Who is the father of Puloma (Sage Bhrigu's wife)?

Tags: bhrigu

The Adi Parva of The Mahabharata contains the story of Sage Bhrigu and his wife Puloma. The story mentions that her father had once (in the past) promised her hand in marriage to a Rakshasa called Puloman.

I wanted to find out the name of Puloma's father but did not come across any reference.

Does anyone know the names of Puloma's father?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide link ? Because srimad bhagavat purana tells a different story.
From [S.B 3.24.22](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/24/22-23/) and [S.B 3.24.23](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/24/22-23/)

> **Kardama Muni handed over his daughter** Kalā to Marīci, and another daughter, Anasūyā, to Atri. He delivered Śraddhā to Aṅgirā, and Havirbhū to Pulastya. He delivered Gati to Pulaha, the chaste Kriyā to Kratu, **Khyāti to Bhṛgu,** and Arundhatī to Vasiṣṭha.

Comment: there r 3 famous wives of Bhṛgu: Godess Laxmi's mother (Khyati), sage Chyavana's mother Puloma, Shukracharya's mother Kavyamata..

Comment: The story of Sage Chyavana and his mother Pauloma is mentioned in the Mahabharata: Adi Parva, Ch.5-6.